# Как правильно обратиться к значению в массиве массивов?

Tags: python, оптимизация

Пусть вновь имеются N станций и таблица цен на проезд между ними. Требуется найти все такие пары станций, для которых дешевле проехать от одной до другой с одной пересадкой через какую-то третью станцию, чем напрямую.

**Формат ввода**
На первой строке вводится натуральное число N — количество станций.
Далее следует N-1 строка, составляющая половину таблицы цен, как в предыдущих задачах на эту тему.

**Формат вывода**
Выводится список пар номеров станций, удовлетворяющих условию (каждая пара — через пробел). Пары должны быть отсортированы по возрастанию по первому номеру, затем — по второму, и пары не должны повторяться, в том числе с изменённым порядком номеров в паре.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается разделить массив на массив из 2-х значений, функция просто ничего не делит, подскажите как правильно обратиться к нужному мне элементу матрицы и прописать это в коде?

```
import operator
n = int(input())
array = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
for i in range (1, n):
    array[i] = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
    array[i] += [0 for _ in range(n - len(array[i]))]
a = sorted(array, key=operator.itemgetter(0, 1))
def split(arr, count):
    return [arr[n::count] for n in range(count)]
print(split(a, 2))
```

**UPDATE:**

При входных данных как в примере выводит следующее:

```
[[[0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0]], [[1, 1, 1, 0], [10, 10, 0, 0]]]
```

Comment: Что вводится? Что должно получится? Что получается на самом деле?

Comment: @Эникейщик вводится и что должно получиться  в примере выше, а что получается на самом деле сейчас добавлю в вопрос

Comment: Тут у вас на самом деле неправильный алгоритм, судя по всему. А формат вывода уже дело десятое. Зачем вам нужна функция split и что она делает?

Comment: @Эникейщик разделяет по пробелам при вводе

Comment: Хехе, ну можете заодно задать себе вопрос, почему у вас собственная функция (я спрашивал как раз про нее) называется так же, как встроеная :)

Comment: А к элементу в списке из списков обратиться очень просто. Например, ``lst[0][0]`` - первый элемент в первом вложенном списке. Об этом написано в каждом учебнике.

Comment: @Эникейщик получил рабочий код, благодаря вашей рекомендации по неправильному алгоритму

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря совету **Эникейщика** был получен рабочий вариант:

```
n = int(input())
s = [[]] + [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n - 1)]
for a in range(0, n - 1):
    for a1 in range(a + 1, n):
        g = s[max(a, a1)][min(a, a1)]
        b = -1
        for i in range(n):
            if i != a and i != a1:
                l_new = s[max(i, a)][min(i, a)] + s[max(i, a1)][min(i, a1)]
                g, b = (l_new, i) if (g > l_new) else (g, b)
        if b != -1:
            print(a, a1)
```